# Wrong image series by using emmet

Tags: html, css, emmet, shorthand

Hi I am using Emmet plugin for html coding, I am having a problem in serializing the image, can someone help me on this.

```
.row>.col-xs-6*2>p.img*2>img[src="gallery-$.jpg"]
```

this code is generating following code

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-1.jpg" alt=""></p>
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-2.jpg" alt=""></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-1.jpg" alt=""></p>
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-2.jpg" alt=""></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However I am expecting images to seralize properly like following

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-1.jpg" alt=""></p>
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-2.jpg" alt=""></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-3.jpg" alt=""></p>
        <p class="img"><img src="gallery-4.jpg" alt=""></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible with this  `.row>.col-xs-6*2>p.img*2>img[src="gallery-$.jpg"]` ,
as `$` will only loop twice `'.col-xs-6*2'`

```
.row>(.col-xs-6>p.cls*2>img[src="gallery-$.jpg"])+(.col-xs-6>p.cls*2>img[src="gallery-$@3.jpg"])
```

This will produce the following

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="cls"><img src="gallery-1.jpg" alt=""></p>
        <p class="cls"><img src="gallery-2.jpg" alt=""></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="cls"><img src="gallery-3.jpg" alt=""></p>
        <p class="cls"><img src="gallery-4.jpg" alt=""></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is @3 is doing here ?

Comment: @DanishAdeel Numbering starts from 3